# Powershell Invoke-Expression seems to keep a file handle after finishing

Tags: powershell

```
1. Invoke-Expression 'C:\setup.exe -url="http://mywebsite.com"' | Out-Null
2. Invoke-Expression 'C:\Tools\delcert.exe "c:\setup.exe"'
```

As you can see on line 1 I am updating my setup.exe which is successful. On the second line I am getting an error from `delcert.exe` and I think it's because the setup.exe has not been fully disposed of in line 1.

Should `Out-Null` wait until the file is closed and there is no longer any reference to it? **If I comment out line 1 then line two is successful.** Additionally if I run these two commands in separate cmd windows I don't get any issues. Thoughts?

Inside `delcert.exe` this is the code that it fails on (to give you context on what the actual problem is).

```
_tprintf(_TEXT("Stripping file: %s.\n"), pszFileName);
hFile = CreateFile(pszFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
    dwResult = GetLastError();
    _tprintf(_TEXT("CreateFile failed with error 0x%08x\n"), dwResult);
    goto cleanupAndExit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a timing issue.  Setup.exe may be running asynchronously.

Try it using `start-process` instead:

```
Start-Process c:\Setup.exe -argumentlist '-url=http://mywebsite.com' -wait
```

That'll wait for setup to finish before calling delcert.

Comment: This appears to have solved it. So all of the arguments need to go in quotes so this would be valid for your example - `'-url="some value" -location="another value"'`?

Comment: I usually do the arguments as a string array when I have multiples.  You'll need to test that syntax to find out.

Comment: I ended up going with `-ArgumentList "-url='"some value'""` If you don't wrap the arguments list in double quotes it won't evaluate the powershell variables, however if you actually need quotes around something you have to escape them with the backtick (I used single quotes here). I will look into the string array.